# Assigning a struct member-array to another struct-array

Tags: c, struct, variable-assignment, imperative

I have to structs defined as:

```
typedef struct {
  char weekday[WEEKDAY_SIZE], 
       start_time[START_TIME_SIZE], 
       home_team[TEAM_SIZE], 
       away_team[TEAM_SIZE], 
       spectators[SPECTATOR_SIZE];

  int day, month, year, round, home_team_score, away_team_score;
} MATCH;

typedef struct {
  MATCH match[MATCH_PR_ROUND];
} ROUND;
```

The structs filled in main function:

```
ROUND round[33];
MATCH equal_four_goal_matches[198];
```

I need to assign a round (eg. an array of matches) to another corresponding array of matches that is within certain conditions.

```
  for(i=0; i<ROUNDS_PR_SEASON; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<MATCH_PR_ROUND; j++) { 
      int match_is_draw = round[i].match[j].home_team_score == round[i].match[j].away_team_score;
      int total_goals = round[i].match[j].home_team_score + round[i].match[j].away_team_score;

      if(match_is_draw && total_goals <= 4) {
        /* Trying to assign each match round[i].match[j] to the new array */
        round[i].match[j] = equal_four_goal_matches[k];
        k++;
        (*length)++;
      }
    }
  }
```

So basically i am trying to assign an array of a struct-member to another array of structs of the same type as the member.

Have used printf to see if anything is stored in the members of the new struct array, but it does not contain anything. No errors while compiling with ANSI89 option and gcc.

Any help is **much appreciated**.

Comment: What does printing the members of `equal_four_goal_matches[k]` have to do with struct assignment?  You're not assigning anything **to** that struct, at least not in the code fragments you've presented.  Your best chances for a good answer will come from presenting a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: The printing of the members of equal_four_goal_matches[k] speaks to whether the assignment was successfully completed. When I am printing the members of the new struct (equal_four_goal_matches) there are no values stored in the members. Therefore something must be wrong with the assignment.

Comment: I have tried to update the description to the best of my ability @JohnBollinger

Comment: It looks like you are not quite sure which way the assignment goes. Try `equal_four_goal_matches[k] = round[i].match[j]`;

Comment: @n.m. **Thank you**! You are completely right.